# Unescaped messages in Play 2.0

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am playing a little bit with Play 2.0.

Now I have a problem regarding html elements in the message file.

I have the following template extract:

```
<footer>
  @Messages("footer")
</footer>
```

And in the file conf/messages I have:

```
footer= Test &reg;
```

When the page is displayed, the message is escaped and displayed as

```
Test &amp; reg;
```

I do not want the message to be escaped!  I want my html element (®) displayed as it is!  But it is not working.

How can I provide the string, so that no escaping takes place?  I have tried the following to no avail:

```
footer= Test \&reg;
footer= Test '&reg;'
footer= test '&'reg;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have HTML element in your translation strings you should include them as follows in the template:

```
@Html(Messages("footer"))
```

Or did I completely misunderstood your question?

Comment: Perfect!  I didn't know about it.  Anyway, I think it is not so nice that I have to modify my template in order to display this element.  it should be better if I could do it directly in the messages file...